# Erro de CORS Ionic 3

Tags: laravel, ionic3, cors

Estou tentando conectar o meu aplicativo com um servidor backend em Laravel

Possuo um interceptador que adiciona os cabeçalhos na requisição:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
console.log('----------------- SESSION -----------------');
console.log(this.session.token);

this.token = this.session.token;
const headers = this.buildRequestHeaders();
const authRequest = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
  }
});

return next.handle(authRequest);
```

}

Já no servidor tenho um middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Helpers\JsonResponseHelper;
use Closure;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken;

class JwtCheck extends GetUserFromToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    if (strpos($request->headers->get("Authorization"), "Bearer ") === false) {
        $request->headers->set("Authorization", "Bearer " . $request->headers->get("Authorization"));
    }

    if (!$token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
        $data['errors'] = trans('auth.failed');
        $message = trans('auth.failed');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    }
    try {
        //$user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate($token);
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        $data['errors'] = trans('messages.token-expired');
        $message = trans('messages.token-expired');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        $data['errors'] = $e->getMessage();
        $message = trans('messages.error');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
        $data['errors'] = $e->getMessage();
        $message = trans('messages.error');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data['errors'] = $e->getMessage();
        $message = trans('messages.error');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    }
    if (!$user) {
        $data['errors'] = trans('auth.failed');
        $message = trans('auth.failed');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    }
    $request->merge(array("user" => $user));
    $request->merge(array("token" => $token));

    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Esse é o meu problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a requisição enviada para o servidor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Primeiro, não poste código como imagem; o site, que é voltado a programação, suporta perfeitamente a formação de código fonte, by @AndersonCarlosWoss. Deixa só as duas ultimas imagens.

Answer (score -1):

Caso tenha acesso a sua aplicação backend, configure o CORS em sua aplicação laravel, caso não possua e esteja realizando acesso localhost, configure o proxy do seu frontend, porém quando for realizar o build para colocar em produção, ai teria de configurar proxy em servidor, por isso recomendo a configuração do CORS em seu laravel backend